# FFMPEG How to do segments encoding in MXF XDCAM HD422

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to encode a feed from a Decklink card to MXF XDCAM HD422 by segment, so I use the following command line:

```
ffmpeg.exe -f dshow -video_size 1920x1080 -r 25 -pixel_format uyvy422 -rtbufsize 702000k -framerate 25 ^
-i video="Decklink Video Capture":audio="Decklink Audio Capture" ^
-c:v mpeg2video -b:v 50M -maxrate 50M -minrate 50M -bf 2 -g 12 ^
-r 25 -pix_fmt yuv422p ^
-filter_complex "[0:a]channelsplit=channel_layout=stereo[left][right]" ^
-acodec pcm_s24le -ar 48000 -map 0:0 -map "[left]" -map "[right]" -f mxf ^
-flags +ilme+ildct -top 1 ^
-f segment -segment_time 20 -segment_atclocktime 1 -strftime 1 -reset_timestamps 1 ^
"REC__%%d-%%m-%%Y__%%Hh%%Mm%%Ss__XDCAM_422_Field_UP.MXF"
```

The command line works fine, but the resulting segments are incorrect.
**Segments after the first segment always have the first three frames duplicated with the third frame !!!**
Regardless of the version of ffmpeg I use, they all have the same behavior.

Does any one know how to achive this correctly? or is it a Bug?
I have submitted a report to the FFmpeg bug tracker: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/9577

Any hint is very welcome.

Happy New Year.